# Windows 8 Reinstalation and License

Tags: windows-8

I have a computer with Windows 8 and I want to delete it and install Linux (I know you can have both instaled, but I want to have Linux only) The question is: Could I reinstall it  later? (I know I could use some eye-parched version, but having the official license...)

Comment: I presume that your W8 has an OEM licence, so you could install it only on the same machine. As the safest option, I would shrink the OS partition to a minimum and leave it there as a dual-boot even if you never boot it. But, provided you retain the recovery partition / disc, you can always re-install to the delivered state, though this would entirely remove all your Linux work, which would need to be backed up elsewhere before restoring W8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You have bought a License, so it is yours to use.

There are some caviats to this - if your license was OEM (bought wiht the computer) - you can only reinstall it on that specific computer, you may have issues activating and need to phone Microsoft (there's a toll-free number in most countries for this) for an activation code - but they usually give them out if you explain you merely formatted your machine